# Accordion nav, add a level of depth

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am working with an otherwise perfect script found here:http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/vertical-accordion/#comment-338149. The only issue is that adding more than one level does not work. I've gone through tutorials like mad and per the author's page it should work.

I added the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5mSwk/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e) {
        if ($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
            $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
            $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

            // open our new menu and add the open class
            $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }

        else if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
        }
    });
});
```

Other accordion scripts I've tried break an image gallery on the same page (bxSlider) even wrapped with no conflict. I've tried more than 14 different menus and 30+ tutorials attempting to get one of them to work without conflicts.

The only benefit is that I'm nearly bald pulling my hair out so at least most of the grays are gone. Any push in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: are you using jquery 1.6 or 1.7

Comment: TypeError: $(...).on is not a function in fiddle use jQuery 1.9

Comment: It seems to be working fine if you use jQuery >= 1.7 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mSwk/2/

Comment: what version of jQuery you are using...?

Comment: Try to use jquery version greater than 1.6.otherwise .on() will not work

Comment: Updated jquery, but it still completely ignores an additional level. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mSwk/2/ The first item "women" has a working submenu "fall/winter", the submenu after that won't open. It looks like it has something to do with the first line of js #nav > li > a. I know this will sound ignorant, but I thought maybe that is limiting the number of sublevels that can be included?